# Visual Studio Tagged Match Higlight wont change color

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2015, syntax-highlighting

How do I change the highlight-color of opening and closing tags when I click of of them?

```
<body>
   foo
</body>
```

Its working right now but I want to change the color
I already tried
-Brace matching,brace matching (highlight) and brace matching(rectangle)
I set the background color to red, but the highlight of tags are still black.
I'm working on .cshtml by the way

Answer (score 0):

Follow this path:

**Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Text Editor**

from the "Display Items" list, select "HTML Razor" related ones and change fonts and colors of them.